# Servo issue, won't go into negative range

Tags: lcd, servo, code-review, ir

I'm trying to create a small laser "turret" with x-axis control. The arduino receives input through IR sensor. I'm having a problem where my servo will preform my up and reset function(moves and prints as intended), but When i preform the down function the servo does not move. I believe the function is executing (it outputs angle to LCD and text to serial monitor) but there is no movement.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
#include <IRremote.h>
#include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h>
#include <Servo.h>

int IRPIN = 3;
int angle = 0;
int test = 0;
IRrecv irrecv(IRPIN);
decode_results results;
Servo spinnything;
LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(0x27, 2, 1, 0, 4, 5, 6, 7, 3, POSITIVE);

void setup()
{
    irrecv.enableIRIn();
    lcd.begin(16, 2);
    lcd.backlight();
    spinnything.attach(5);
    spinnything.write(angle);
    lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
    lcd.print("WARNING");
    lcd.setCursor(2, 1);
    lcd.print("!!!LASER!!!");
    delay(1500);
    lcd.clear();
}

void loop()
{
    if (irrecv.decode(&results)) {
        irrecv.resume();
    }
    if (results.value == 0xE172C837) {
        up();
        results.value = 0x00000000;
    }
    if (results.value == 0xE17228D7) {
        down();
        results.value = 0x00000000;
    }if (results.value == 0xE1724CB3) {
        reset();
        results.value = 0x00000000;
    }
    lcd.setCursor(0,0);
    delay(10);
}

void up() {
    if (angle < 180) {
        angle = angle + 18;
        spinnything.write(angle);
        lcd.clear();
        lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
        lcd.print("Current Angle");
        lcd.setCursor(3, 1);
        lcd.print("=");
        lcd.setCursor(5, 1);
        lcd.print(angle);
        Serial.print("up");
    }
}
void down() {
    if (angle > -180) {
        angle = angle - 18;
        spinnything.write(angle);
        lcd.clear();
        lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
        lcd.print("Current Angle");
        lcd.setCursor(3, 1);
        lcd.print("=");
        lcd.setCursor(5, 1);
        lcd.print(angle);
        Serial.print("down");
    }
}
int reset() {
    angle = 0;
    spinnything.write(angle);
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
    lcd.print("Current Angle");
    lcd.setCursor(3, 1);
    lcd.print("=");
    lcd.setCursor(5, 1);
    lcd.print(angle);
    Serial.print("reset");

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all `Servo.write(int)` takes a value ranging from 0 to 180 degrees. 
Then, servos themselves can only move from 0 to 180 usually. Some can do more, some can do less. But regardless of how much a servo actually moves, you should expect that doing `Servo.write(0)` the servo would rotate all the way to one side, doing `Servo.write(180)` it should go to the other side, doing `Servo.write(90)` it should stay in the middle.

Also, `lcd.setCursor(5, 1);` is basically useless as the lcd driver itself would advance the cursor as the previous characters are written. Just do `lcd.print("= ");` if you want an additional space between the equals symbol and the number

Comment: Thanks so much Valerio! My project is now working thanks to you. Time to go fire up the 3d printer for a base. :)